# HttpURLConnection POST returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android

I have tried every single question about it in here, but my code still returning 400, for every request that I try to do and I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

InputStream in = null;

try {

    URL url = new URL(uri);

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    String query = "";

    if (Validator.isNotNull(paramsMap) && !paramsMap.isEmpty()) {

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : paramsMap.entrySet()) {

            builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
    }

    if (!query.isEmpty()) {

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        os.close();

    }

    connection.connect();

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (status == 200) {

        in = connection.getInputStream();
    } else {
        in = connection.getErrorStream();
    }

} finally {

    connection.disconnect();
}

return in;
```

Comment: Do you have access to the API's logs on the remote server? Your code to establish the connection looks ok, but without knowing what you're supposed to be sending or what your API expects I don't think there's enough information to go on.

Comment: What do you understand about 400 status?

Comment: @MichaelDodd it's supposed to send 3 parameters, username, email and grant_type, and it's exactly what I'm doing with Uri.Builder, I've debbuged and it's doing right, I guess.

Comment: Even if you're making a request by other means e.g through curl?

Comment: @MichaelDodd no, by curl it's ok. It's why I thought I was doing something wrong, and can't know what. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to get it working using a separate tool (there are quite a few browser plugins that let you create POST requests (Postman, HttpRequester, etc.)  Use one of those to figure out exactly what you need to POST to get it to work. Once you have it working in one of the tools, you can do the same thing in your Java code.